# How to connect Smart TV to Time Capsule?

Tags: video, time-capsule, streaming

I want to be able to copy movies on a Time Capsule and watch them on my Smart TV (Philips 32PFH5500) without the computer on.

How can I set this up?

Comment: What is a "time machine or similar device"? What kind of Smart TV are you using?

Comment: I meant time capsule. Sorry. I was thinking about buying the Philips 32PFH5500.

Answer (score 1):

Time Capsule shares files via SMB protocol, so if your TV can connect to a networ share, you are good to go.

If your TV cannot do that, you'd have to jailbreak the TC since it doesn't allow running apps or media streaming code out of the box.